# gcsfuse to transfer files from joomla to cloud bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, joomla3.0, gcsfuse

I have a google compute engine with one instance running joomla and another with GC storage bucket. I created a gcsfuse mount point from my joomla instance to the bucket and it works as root user to tranfer files into my bucket from my joomla instance server from command line, however I am not able to find a way to make it work with another unix user created for running my joomla instance..i heed this as my site has a functionality to upload files into bucket directly..any help will be great please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue, you need to give permission for the joomlaUser to access the directory you mounted, or create the directory as the joomlauser.

You should run gcsfuse as the user who will be using the file system, not as root. Do not use sudo.

Comment: I uninstalled the gcsfuse and reinstalled it to run as a joomlaUser but its returning "exit status 1" while mounting the directory and its not even mounting as a root user now

Comment: Where are you trying to mount the directory? Is the joomlaUser user authorized to mount where you are trying to mount?

Comment: I got your point, but now its not mounting even with the root user. Initially it was mounting with root user, now if I mount as root its returning "exit status 1" even though I reinstalled the gcsfuse a number of times....

Comment: can you show where you are trying to mount, and with which user?